# Entity Framework inserting duplicates based on a composite key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to insert a large List of objects into my database (about 30,000 records at a time), and basing if the record is a duplicate row based on a composite key of various columns.  Here's the code to make this a bit more clear:

```
await {db_context}.AddRangeAsync(Metrics.Where(x =>!MetricsInDb.AsEnumerable().Any(y => 
x.CreativeId == y.CreativeId 
&& x.LineItemId == y.LineItemId 
&& x.Date.Date == y.Date.Date 
&& x.City == y.City 
&& x.Country == y.Country 
&& x.Metro == y.Metro 
&& x.State == y.State)));
```

For some further explanation, I have two lists.

`Metrics` is a List of objects I'm inserting.
`MetricsInDb` is another List of objects I'm comparing against.
in the `.Any()`, essentially I'm trying to say, if ALL of these columns are matching, then it's a duplicate. Do not insert that duplicate row.

To me, the logic seems sound. I'm unsure if there's a better way to do this on such a large composite key like this.

I originally had a `.AsParallel()` here.... `Metrics.AsParallel().Where(x => !MetricsInDb.......)` which I removed thinking that was the issue, it's obviously not after a few runs it's still inserting duplicates.

Any and all tips would be super helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put the three or four most specific (least likely to be duplicates) properties as keys to dictionaries, that will cut down on most of the O(n2) operations. Could give you an implementation if you want

Comment: Actually I know one solution but it needs third party EFC Extension. If you ok, I'll prepare sample. I think data will be inserted in several seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The composite key adds a challenge to an operation like this, however the real issue I see with this approach is:

```
Metrics.Where(x =>!MetricsInDb.AsEnumerable().Any( ...
```

This will load all Metrics records from the database into memory. As your table grows this will become unsustainable in terms of performance and resource use.

For larger bulk operations my first choice would probably be *not* to use EF and rather take the process offline/background.

When it comes to bulk operations using EF, the approach I use is to first import all processing records into an empty staging table, then from there you can perform a join between the staging table and the real data. The staging record can declare a relationship back to the Metric row based on the composite key. These two entities (Metrics and StagingMetrics) are registered in a bounded context, being a context aware of just these two entities and their relationship.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StagingMetrics>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.Metric)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(x => new 
    {
        x.CreativeId, 
        x.LineItemId, 
        x.Date.Date,
        x.City,
        x.Country,
        x.Metro,
        x.State
    });
```

To get the Items to add:

```
var newMetrics = stagingDbContext.StagingMetrics.Where(x => x.Metric == null);
```

From there we can convert it back into a Metric. (They are identical, but needs to be cast over so it can be written as a Metric)

```
var newMetrics = stagingDbContext.StagingMetrics.Where(x => x.Metric == null)
    .Select(x => new Metric
    {
        CreativeId = x.CreativeId, 
        LineItemId = x.LineItemId, 
        Date = x.Date,
        City = x.City,
        Country = x.Country,
        Metro = x.Metro,
        State = x.State
    }).ToList();
```

From that, we can add the new Metrics via either the StagingDbContext or the main application DbContext.  The final step to consider would be to truncate the staging table which could be done by an SQL Command:

```
stagingDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE StagingMetrics");
```

I'd consider truncating the table when first running the process.

One consideration of this approach is that the StagingDbContext should be scoped to this operation to avoid the possibility of code referring to rows in the StagingMetrics table after the Truncate.

So a more complete Import method flow might look like:

```
using (var stagingDbContext = StagingDbContextFactory.Create())
{
    stagingDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE StagingMetrics");        

    var newMetrics = stagingDbContext.StagingMetrics.Where(x => x.Metric == null)
    .Select(x => new Metric
    {
        CreativeId = x.CreativeId, 
        LineItemId = x.LineItemId, 
        Date = x.Date,
        City = x.City,
        Country = x.Country,
        Metro = x.Metro,
        State = x.State
    }).ToList();

    if (newMetrics.Any())
    {
        AppDbContext.Metrics.AddRange(newMetrics);
        AppDbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    // Can truncate the Staging table here as well, or leave the contents to debug if there was an issue.
}
```

Where StagingDbContextFactory is a factory class to return a new instance of the DbContext and AppDbContext is the injected main application DbContext.

This would not be a process that can be triggered piece-meal such as part of a web request given multiple calls could attempt to truncate the staging table prior to a previous call being completed. If this can be performed as part of something like an Upload or similar requests from users then record the request to a processing queue with a background worker ensuring only one import is being processed at a time.

Comment: Awesome answer, I'll look into implementing a solution like this because it might be the best way.  I have many different processes similar to this one, so I can do something similar for them all.  As for your last point on it being triggered piece-meal, that shouldn't be an issue since this is running as a cron job, scheduled once daily.